# Change results from query according to a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with several results from different years. My first year is my decision year (all the years after are according the first year). And my first year column is in a descending order by the count of the result in it.
This is an example of how my table looks like.

```
+----+------+-------+------+------+
| ID | Year | ID2   |Year1 |Year2 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+
|  1 | 1    | 12    |B     |      |
|  1 | 1    | 13    |B     |      |
|  1 | 1    | 22    |A     |      |
|  1 | 2    | 12    |      |B     |
|  1 | 2    | 15    |      |A     |
|  1 | 2    | 17    |      |C     |
|  1 | 2    | 25    |      |C     |
|  1 | 2    | 30    |      |D     |
+----+------+-------+------+------+
```

The columns `Year1` and `Year2` need to be changed to numbers. The first result will be 1 (so, B will turn to 1) and the second will be 2 (so, A will turn to 2) and so on.

The column `Year1` is the main column which will decide what will be in column `Year2`. Which means, the results in column `Year2` will get the results from column `Year1` (B=1, A=2) but once a new result is introduced the result will increment by 1 (C will be 3 and D will be 4)

So the table should look like this.

```
+----+------+-------+------+------+
| ID | Year | ID2   |Year1 |Year2 |
+----+------+-------+------+------+
|  1 | 1    | 12    |1     |      |
|  1 | 1    | 13    |1     |      |
|  1 | 1    | 22    |2     |      |
|  1 | 2    | 12    |      |1     |
|  1 | 2    | 15    |      |2     |
|  1 | 2    | 17    |      |3     |
|  1 | 2    | 25    |      |3     |
|  1 | 2    | 30    |      |4     |
+----+------+-------+------+------+
```

Plus, the columns go until `Year10` and columns `ID`,`Year` and `ID2` create a key.

Any ideas will help at this point. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A rough way to do it would be to do each year data in separate temp tables.

Then create another set of temp tables to determine the numbering of letter using something like row_number().

Update your letters with the numbers.

And finally union them together.